# Wicket retrieve javascript variable to use in java

Tags: javascript, ajax, parameters, callback, wicket

I am trying to retrieve a javascript variable using Java. I think that I am close to the solution.

I want to retrieve the width of an element on my panel. To achieve this, I added a behavior to my panel that adds the callback and retrieves the parameters (width and height).

```
private class ImageBehavior extends AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior {

    @Override
    protected void respond(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        //I receive a JavaScript call :)
        StringValue width  = getRequest().getRequestParameters().getParameterValue("width");
        StringValue height = getRequest().getRequestParameters().getParameterValue("height");       
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes) {
        super.updateAjaxAttributes(attributes);
        attributes.getExtraParameters().put("width", "undef");
        attributes.getExtraParameters().put("height", "undef");
    }

    @Override
    public void renderHead(Component component, IHeaderResponse response) {
        super.renderHead(component, response);
        response.render(OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript(getCallbackScript().toString()));

    }
}
```

In javascript, the following code gets called:

```
function callbackWicketNewImage(element) {
    var wcall = Wicket.Ajax.get({ 'u': 'callbackUrl', 'ep' : {'width': element.width(), 'height': element.height()}});
}
```

When the js-code is called, the 'respond' method gets called but the values of the width and height parameter did not change. They remained 'undef'.

Comment: Maybe element.width() and element.height() return undef? Do you actually update these values on the page in JS or something?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The element.width and element.height methods do return the right values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed my problem with the following code. Please note that the abstract onResponse method is for abstraction purposes.

```
public abstract class SizeBehavior extends AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior {

@Override
protected void respond(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    IRequestParameters request = RequestCycle.get().getRequest().getRequestParameters();
    onResponse(request.getParameterValue("widthParam").toDouble(),
            request.getParameterValue("heightParam").toDouble());
}

@Override
protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes) {
    super.updateAjaxAttributes(attributes);
    attributes.getDynamicExtraParameters()
    .add("return {'widthParam': $(" + getComponent().getMarkupId() + ").width(), " +
                 "'heightParam': $(" + getComponent().getMarkupId() + ").height()}");
}

public void renderHead(Component component, IHeaderResponse response) {
    response.render(OnLoadHeaderItem.forScript(getCallbackScript().toString()));
}

public abstract void onResponse(double width, double height);
}
```

Behavior call:

```
add(new SizeBehavior() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(double width, double height) {
        //set vars..
        widthVar = width;
        heightVar = height;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `response` method should look like this:

```
@Override
  protected void respond(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    RequestCycle cycle = RequestCycle.get();
    WebRequest webRequest = (WebRequest) cycle.getRequest();
    StringValue param1 = webRequest.getQueryParameters().getParameterValue("param1");
    StringValue param2 = webRequest.getQueryParameters().getParameterValue("param2");
    // do whatever you need with param1 and param2
  }
```

You use `getRequestParameters()`. It should be `getQueryParameters()`

EDIT: see also this article: http://thombergs.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/rolling-your-own-ajax-behavior-with-wicket

Comment: Unfortunately this did not change anything.